# Android SharedPreferences xml, onChange update WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have an Activity named MyActivity. MyActivity uses WebView to show web pages.
I also have an options activity like below. O also have `/res/xml/options.xml`
When user changes something in the options, I run `MyUtility.setOptionsChanged()` method.

My problem is when user changes something in preferences XML. When user presses back button I need to reload the current webview URL with post data ?

Can you check the code below and where should I put that logic ? Should I add to MyOptionsActivity's onKeyDown method or ?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myweb);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

        String postData = MyUtility.getOptionsDataForPOSTURL(mContext);
        mWebView.postUrl("http://example.com", EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
    }

    public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               String postData = MyUtility.getOptionsDataForPOSTURL(mContext);
               view.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}

  public class MyOptionsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
            implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("myoptions");
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
       getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        MyUtility.setOptionsChanged(mContext,true);
    }
  }


public class MyUtility {
    public static void setOptionsChanged(Context pContext, Boolean pOptionsChanged) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = pContext.getSharedPreferences("general", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("optionsChanged", pOptionsChanged);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Place your code to reload webview in onRestart method of MyActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to @Hiren Dabhi's comment, best place is Activity's onRestart method. It worked good.